# java - reading config file in same directory as jar file

Tags: java

I have a simple program in Intellij that I made just to test out reading file path of config file.

I created a simple test case where I would use a timer to print "Hello world" periodically in N intervals where N is in milliseconds and N is configurable.

This is the code:

```
public void schedule() throws Exception {

       Properties props=new Properties();

        String path ="./config.properties";
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(path);
        BufferedReader in1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
       // InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");

        props.load(in1);
        in1.close();
        int value=Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("value"));






        Timer t=new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      // System.out.println("HELEOELE");

                        try {
                           // test.index();
                            System.out.println("hello ");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
              0,
                value);





    }
```

What I did was I set value as N in a config file where it can be changed by anyone without touching the actual code. So I compiled the jar file, and I placed both config.properties and jar file in same folder or directory. I want to be able to change make N changeable so I don't need to re-compile the jar again and again everytime.

Note: the config properties file is created manually and placed in same directory as the jar. And I am executing the jar in command prompt.

However, it seems when I try to run it, it doesn't recognize the file path.

```
"main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\config.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I've looked into many issues regarding reading config files outside of jar file and none of them worked for me. Am I doing any mistake here?

Comment: How do you start your program?

Comment: Running the jar file in command prompt

Comment: What's your current working directory in the shell that launches the jar? That's where relative path will be searched from. If you're `cd`ing to the jar dir before launching it you should be good, but if you're calling it from another directory that's where the config file will be searched from.

Comment: and in the code you showed you have a slash ("./config.properties"), the error message shows a backslash (".\config.properties")

Comment: Did you try simply `config.properties`? Did you try to diagnose your current path: `System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());`?

Comment: I did not use "cd" . I just wrote " java -jar [full directory of the jar] "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./config.properties` is a relative path that points to a `config.properties` file in the current working directory.

The current working directory, unless changed by `System.setProperty("user.dir", newPath)`, will be the directory from which you launched the JVM currently handling your code.

To get your jar to work as it currently is, you have two ways available :

1. copy the `config.properties` file to the directory you are executing `java` from
2. change the directory you are running `java` from to the one that contains the `config.properties`

---

You may also consider letting the user specify where to get the properties file from :

```
String path = System.getProperty("propertiesLocation", "config.properties");
```

You would then be able to specify a location for the property file when calling your jar :

```
java -jar /path/to/your.jar -DpropertiesLocation=/path/to/your.properties
```

Or call it as you did before to search for the properties at its default location of `config.properties` in the current working directory.

Comment: Wait i am confused, I added the config file to the directory of the jar. That;s it and I called the directory by going " java -jar path of the jar"

Comment: Code wise, did I do any mistake?

Comment: And my config properties is already in same directory as the jar. I am just running the jar file from there.

Comment: Hmm that should work then. Are you running on windows or linux?

Comment: You say you use the full path of the jar in the command line. If you're in the directory of the jar, it should also work with the relative path, e.g. `java -jar name_of_the.jar`, could you try that?

Comment: I am running on windows.

Comment: Shouldn't it work like this way: `java -jar C:/abc/abcd.jar`  too? Wait do I need to `cd` to the path or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I will try tomorrow as I am away from my computer. Will let you know

Comment: `java -jar C:/abc/abcd.jar` can work; I asked you to run `java -jar abcd.jar` to make sure you were actually running from the directory that contains the jar. "do I need to cd to the path" that's one of the two solutions I suggest in my answer. When I told you that should work, I thought you were already at that location, since you mentionned "I am just running the jar file from there".

Comment: I see. So if i understand you correctly, cd to the path of the directory, then execute the command `java -jar abcd.jar`  am i right?

Comment: Is there anything wrong in my code? Because if it still doesn't work then I don't know what to do . Even though the `FileNotFoundException` says it couldn't find `.\config.properties` which got the slash wrongly.

Comment: Since you're running on windows, `.\config.properties` is the correct path (Windows use backslashes as file separator, although Java also handles forward slashes paths).

Comment: So it should be able to read my config properties if my code is correct

Comment: If the directory you're launching the `java` command from contains a `config.properties` file, then yes your current code should run without throwing `java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\config.properties`

Comment: When you say current working directory, it means abc.jar and config.properties are both in the same folder, correct?

Comment: When I say current working directory, I'm referring to the environment of your command line tool (e.g. `cmd` or `powershell`). It's not important for the jar and the properties file to be in the same directory, it's important for your command line tool to be in the directory where the properties file is present when it runs `java -jar C:/what/ever.jar`, because that's going to be the directory in which your Java code searches for the `.\config.properties` file.

Comment: Ok I tested it and it works only if I `cd` to the directory first and then call the `java-jar name of the file` . It doesn't work if i just `java -jar full directory`. Why is that?

Comment: It should work with the full directory as long as you `cd`

Comment: Both `java -jar name.jar` and `java -jar C:/dir/name.jar` should work

Comment: Maybe my code only allows to call the properties once it's in the directory of the jar